# Custom async yup validation for multiple fields

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

Given the sandbox - [https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-hook-form-with-yup-forked](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-hook-form-with-yup-forked-tslcpf?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A28%2C1)

I've created a common test function for all fields which will be an asynchronous API call in the future.

```
test: async (values, { createError }) => {
      await new Promise((res) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          res();
        }, 1000);
      });
      const currentField = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "field1" : "field2";
      const err = createError({
        path: currentField,
        message: "not good" + currentField,
      });
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    },
  })
```

CASES:

- When im typing on field1 and get field1 in currentField, then error is showing properly.
- When im typing on field1 and get field2 in currentField, then field1 error is getting cleared as well as error is not showing for field2.

Is there any way to show error in currentField irrespective of the field im typing in?
I tried adding test function for individual fields but that causes to call my API function 2 times due to 2 fields.